# find -type f still returning directories, how to stop this?

Tags: find

My find command looks like this:

```
find / -mindepth 1 -type f -path /exclude1 -prune -o -path /exclude2 -prune -o -printf '%p %Cs %s\n'
```

The results I get are for example:

```
/lost+found 1151063954 16384
/dir/subdir 1483455984 4096
/dir/subdir/file.properties 1440054032 453
```

Now, I don't want to see the /dir/subdir in the results anymore. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to put the -type f at the end of the search command, but before the printf. It became:

```
find / -mindepth 1 -path /exclude1 -prune -o -path /exclude2 -prune -o -type f -printf '%p %Cs %s\n'
```

Comment: It would be awesome to have an explanation of why the order matters so people can appropriate this answer to other scenarios.